# My SQL UPDATE error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I've been scratching my head for the last hour and just can't get this to work.

Doing this query:

```
$dbtoken = mysql_real_escape_string($invite_token);
$dbexpire = mysql_real_escape_string($invite_expire);
$dbid = mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE inviters SET invitetoken='$dbtoken', inviteexpire='$dbexpire' WHERE uid='$dbid'");
$save = mysql_query($update_user) or die(mysql_error());
```

It gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: there is no need to add integer value into single quote

Comment: Print out the actual SQL statement you I'm sure you'll see the error yourself.

Comment: remove quotes around uid value, echo your sql statement, run it in db test in then put it in your code..

Comment: @Bhumi It is good practive to do so. If the integer was empty, it prevents an sql error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `mysql_query();` twice. Once in the last line. And once in the line above it.

The first time it returns `1` (success)

The second time you try to execute `1` as a query

Ps. Scratching your head for an hour can cause skin irritation.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the result of your first query as an sql statement for your second query:

```
$update_user = mysql_query("UPDATE inviters SET invitetoken='$dbtoken',
inviteexpire='$dbexpire' WHERE uid='$dbid'");
$save = mysql_query($update_user) or die(mysql_error());
```

$update_user contains the result, and you feed it back to mysql_query. Try this instead:

```
$update_user = "UPDATE inviters SET invitetoken='$dbtoken',
inviteexpire='$dbexpire' WHERE uid='$dbid'";
$save = mysql_query($update_user) or die(mysql_error());
```

BTW: Use Mysqli instead of Mysql_ statements, they're deprecated and unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a error You are trying to execute your query twice. Remove second execution of it.i.e remove this

```
 $save = mysql_query($update_user) or die(mysql_error());
```

it is trying to do this

```
$save = mysql_query(1);
```

which is wrong